# Delete an item from a JSON file

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON file which contains capitals and countries.How do I delete a particular key-value pair?

I have the following JSON file

```
{
    "data": [
    {
        "Capital": "Berlin",
        "Country": "Germany"
    },
    {
        "Capital": "New Delhi",
        "Country": "India"
    },
    {
        "Capital": "Canberra",
        "Country": "Australia"
    },
    {
        "Capital": "Beijing.",
        "Country": "China"
    },
    {
        "Capital": "Tokyo",
        "Country": "Japan"
    }
    ]

}
```

I want to remove an item

```
 {
    "Capital": "Canberra",
    "Country": "Australia"
 }
```

How do I do it?I have tried my own way of doing it,but doesn't work

```
with open(filename) as json_data:
        nations = json.load(json_data)['data']
        for x in nations:
            if x['Capital'] == "Canberra":
                del x['Capital']
```

How do I delete the item then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend re-building your JSON, using a list comprehension.

```
nations = json.load(json_data)['data']
nations_new = [x for x in nations if x['Capital'] != "Canberra"]
```

If you have multiple filters, create a `set` of them:

```
filters = {'Canberra', 'Mexico City', ...}
nations_new = [x for x in nations if x['Capital'] not in filters]
```

Finally, save your filtered data:

```
with open(filename, 'w') as json_data:
    json.dump(nations_new, json_data)
```

Comment: @COLDSPEED Hey that would be great!But I have only posted a single JSON file and I actually have multiple JSON files and in each of them,I want to delete a particular item.So I don't think recreating JSON each time would be a good idea.

Comment: @SouvikRay It's cheaper than you think, since you're only moving references around. Unfortunately, you cannot delete within a loop.

Comment: @COLDSPEED Hey one more question.If I do want to retain the original JSON format ({ "data" : [ .... ) since this method recreates the file without retaining the original structure,what do I do?

Comment: @SouvikRay `{'data' : nations_new }` <----- save that instead.

Comment: @COLDSPEED ok got it!